# Is it possible to combine 'DISTINCT' and 'COUNT' queries, so that I can see how many times each distinct value appears?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say that my database was like IMDb, a huge collection of movie titles and their release dates.

```
 TITLE                           DATE

 Terminator 2                    1991
 Tron                            1982
 Karate Kid                      1984
 Silence of the Lambs            1991
```

and I want to issue a query that will return to me data in the form

```
 1991     2
 1982     1
 1984     1
```

Meaning that there are two rows that have '1991' in the year field, one row that has '1982' in that field, etc.

Is there a way I can do this purely with an SQL query, or should I be writing something in my program itself to generate this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of distinct + count it would be group by

```
 select field, count(*) from table group by field
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a *COUNT* and *GROUP BY*, the *DISTINCT* isn't necessary because all the duplicates are already eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select date as year ,count(*) as movie_count from table group by date;
```